# VBA PowerPoint - Graph Type Radar - Category Labels Left and Top positions

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is it possible know the position left and top for each category labels?

[image: ImageRadarGraph]

Thanks ...

Comment: The answer is Yes.

Comment: Could you show me how please?